# Reading .aws/credentials file with Scala for hadoop conf setting from spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3

How can I just read my different aws profiles I have located in my `credentials` file within `.aws` directory? Just want to have my app read in the access key and secret such as below but not sure how to make this point to the credentials file.

```
object S3KeyStore extends Serializable {
  private val keyMap = Map(String, S3Key)

  def load(key: String)(implicit sc: SparkContext) = keyMap.get(key) match {
    case Some(k) =>
      val hc = sc.hadoopConfiguration
      hc.set("fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId", k.access)
      hc.set("fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey", k.secret)
      true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Spark summit will automatically set credentials from the AWS env vars; be aware that they can stamp on anything you've set in spark-defaults/core-site.
2. If you use S3A, I think it might use those credentials (it takes a list of auth mechanisms; I'll have a look to see if it does this one).
3. You can set up your core-site.xml in Hadoop/YARN to pick up secrets from another directory. I do this in testing, [via XInclude](http://steveloughran.blogspot.com.es/2016/04/testing-against-s3-and-object-stores.html).
4. S3A in Hadoop 2.8+ will also handle IAM auth in EC2 VMs, and encoding secrets in encrypted JCEKS files (which can be shared across the cluster so secrets are never sent in clear text in job submission). It also supports session keys, so you can issue some credentials for a short period of time.